# Downsides of the undo-action approach for slow connections

Tags: application-state

Trello does the undo-approach. Instead of showing a loader after adding a member to a card, they immediately add it to the board, and then undo the action if an error occurs. In addition, they show a growl about the error.

My question is, is this UX fine for slow connections? Is misinformation the only big downside (that the user thought that the members were added successfully although they weren't yet) if for example they immediately closed down the application even before the request even made it? Are there any ways to mitigate or prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display something like a modal that you will hook to onbeforeunload to confirm that the user wants to close the app.

To show that the item is not added to the backend, you could either:
1. Use a short text instead of a spinner
2. Make the item in progress semi-transparent